# Tornado Startup Management

Tags: linux, python, supervisord, tornado

**I have an application written to run in Tornado server..**

The application should start on boot, and if it fails ( be restarted )

Currently I am using *supervisord*, but i wanted to see what else is available that might be better..

Anyone have suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Lots of solutions laid out here:

[How to relaunch an executable if it dies](https://serverfault.com/questions/59486/how-to-relaunch-an-executable-if-it-dies)

Comment: I dont think init will work...